# How to resolve integrity error in my Django project

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a form that an admin uses to register student when he logs into the website. I extended the 
Django User model to accommodate things like gender, 
phone, profile_pic, time. Each time  I fill the 
fields I get this error **UNIQUE constraint failed: backend_extenduser.user_id**
on the browser when I scroll down a little bit I see this 
**The above exception (UNIQUE constraint failed: backend_extenduser.user_id) was the direct cause of the following exception**
I want to know what is causing this? And how I can solve this 
I have another project that has the same code base, this project works fine but this very project I am working on is throwing error. Below are my codes

**on models.py**

```
class ExtendUser(models.Model):
    MALE = 'ML'
    FEMALE = 'FM'
    GENDER = [
        (MALE, 'Male'),
        (FEMALE, 'Female'),
    ]
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Profile Picture', blank=True, null=True, upload_to='backend_uploads')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=GENDER, default=MALE, blank=False, null=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**I want to reduce my forms.py to show only the code 
that I adds addtional field to the Django User Model**

```
class ExtendUserForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta():
        MALE = 'ML'
        FEMALE = 'FM'
        GENDER = [
            (MALE, 'Male'),
            (FEMALE, 'Female'),
        ]
        model = ExtendUser
        exclude = ('time', 'user')
        widgets = {
            'phone':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'gender':forms.RadioSelect(choices=GENDER),
            'profile_pic':forms.ClearableFileInput()
        }
```

On my **views.py** I have the code below, you can see on the code below I have
imported the **Register()** class which was created on **forms.py**. I am trying 
not to show the whole code to avoid it being too bulky

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        register_form = Register(request.POST)
        extend_form = ExtendUserForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if register_form.is_valid() and extend_form.is_valid():
            form1 = register_form.save()
            form2 = extend_form.save(commit=False)
            form2.user = form1
            extend_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Student have been registered successfully')
    else:
        register_form = Register()
        extend_form = ExtendUserForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    return render(request, 'backend/add-student.html', {'reg':register_form, 'ext':extend_form})
```

**on my template**

```
<form  method="post" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ reg }}
            {{ ext }}
           {% csrf_token %}
           <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Add Student">
</form>
```

Comment: After setting `form2.user`, you should call `form2.save()` instead of `extend_form.save()`. The form's save method returns the model instance, so `user =  register_form.save()` and `extended_user = extend_form.save()` would be better.

Comment: `time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)` could be replaced with `auto_now=True`, or `auto_add_now=True`

Comment: Thanks, but that did not work

Comment: On views.py, in the else statement, you are passing `request.POST` and `request.FILES` to `ExtendUserForm`. It is supposed it is a GET request, so I think that is wrong and should be empty. I don't think that is causing the error though...

Comment: @oz19 thanks for your response, but this is not responsible for the error

Comment: Despite the fact that your code does have some issues (see comments) I cannot reproduce your error. Your ```ExtendUser``` is not created anywhere in addition to your register viw, e.g. by some ```post_save``` signal or an overriden method?

Comment: @Chris thanks for your reply, my ExtendUser is called in forms.py where you model = ExtendUser insdie the meta class